# Does the iOS Camera Roll contain all of my photos and videos, incl. what's in my albums?

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app, album, camera-roll

I have tons of photos in my iPhone Camera Roll. I have also created albums and moved photos around from the camera roll to different albums.

Is it true that the Camera Roll actually contains "all" the photos and videos I have?

I ask because I am going to make a copy of all my photos and do not want to use iCloud etc.

**If I just copy everything in my Camera Roll to my PC hard drive, will that get everything I have in all the albums I have created?**

Or must I copy the Camera Roll and all the Albums to ensure I get everything?

I know the organization or my photos will be goofy etc, but I just want all my photos and videos from my iPhone on my PC without using any cloud based services.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on iPhones, Camera Roll includes all photos, live photos, videos, screenshots, slo-mos and timelapses you have on your phone, even if some or all of them are in albums. You can plug your phone into your computer and copy your photos from the storage device that appears in your operating system's native file manager. You can also make a backup of your phone in iTunes and using a backup extractor tool, such as iMazing, recover the photos.